# Variable nesting in Python

Tags: python, variables, automation, nested

Basically, I need to make my program able to create multiple (unlimited) variables for me, that I will still be able to use manipulate through my code, without me defining them.

I was thinking to have a letter and a number as the variable name, such as a1, and have the program create new variables just adding 1 to the number. So it would create **a1** through **a30** or so. How would I do this?

My program is going to add polynomials and the variables (or list now) is to separate the different monomials, and since I don't know how many monomials there will be in the polynomial, I needed a way to make the number flexible so I have an exact amout of spaces for the monomials, no extras, and no less.

Here's the code:

```
# Sample polynomial set to x, the real code will say x = (raw_input("Enter a Polynomial")).

x = '(5xx + 2y + 2xy)+ (4xx - 1xy)'

# Isdigit command set to 't' to make the code easier to write.
t = str.isdigit

# Defining v for later use.
v = 0

# Defining 'b' which will be the index number that the program will look at.
b = 1

# Creating 'r' to parse the input to whatever letter is next.
r = x [b]

# Defining n which will be used later to tell if the character is numeric.
n = 0

# Defining r1 which will hold one of the monomials, ( **will be replaced with a list**)

#This was the variable in question.
r1 = ''

# Setting 'p' to evaluate if R is numeric ( R and T explained above).
p = t(r)

# Setting 'n' to 1 or 0 to replace having to write True or False later.
if p == True:
    n = 1
else:
    n = 0

# Checking if r is one of the normal letters used in Algebra, and adding it to a variable
if r == 'x':
    v = 'x'
    c = 1
elif r == 'y':
    v = 'y'
    c = 1
elif r == 'z':
    v = 'z'
    c = 1

# If the character is a digit, set c to 0, meaning that the program has not found a letter yet (will be used later in the code).
elif n == 1:
    v = r
    c = 0

# Adding what the letter has found to a variable (will be replaced with a list).
r1 = r1 + v

b = b + 1
```

I will eventually make this a loop.

I added comments to the code so it's more understandable.

Comment: this is why people invented arrays..

Comment: In Python, this is a ``list`` or a ``set``. I suggest you learn the basics of the language before trying to do any more - data structures are a very basic concept.

Comment: i know the difference between a list and a variable, i need a variable, did you read the question and i do know the basics i've read all about lists

Comment: And gokcehan, what attribute of the array command will help, because im looking at this list and im not sure what you mean http://docs.python.org/library/array.html

Comment: @Nick: "i know the difference between a list and a variable, i need a variable" -- what do you think is the difference between variables and list elements?

Comment: Variables can change and can contain lists while lists are predefined

Comment: @Nick sort of, and no, respectively. I suggest you read the [two](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) [sections](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) of the tutorial that deal with lists. I'm also fond of pointing people to [this blog post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) when they have this sort of problem.

Comment: The point is that _lists are mutable_, and so can have things added and removed from them dynamically. If you need to manipulate (say) 30 equivalent objects, the way to do it is to put them in a list and access them element-wise (eg `variable_list[5] += 3` to add 3 to the 6th number in the list). You _don't_ want 30 confusingly-named variables knocking about - it makes much more sense to keep them all in the same place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, you are trying to programmatically, dynamically modify the heap space where the variables live. I really do not think this is possible. If it is, it is very obscure.

I do understand where you are coming from. When I was first learning to program I had thought to solve problems in ways that would require such "dynamically created" variables. The solution really is to recognize what kind of (collection) data structure fits your needs.

If you want variables `a1` through `a30`, create a list `a`. Then `a1` would be `a[1]`, `a30` would be `a[30]`. It is a little different to write, but it should give you the behavior you need.

Comment: It _is_ possible to dynamically create variables in Python (everything is possible!). That's what `globals()` and `locals()` (among others) are for. There's usually a better way to do it though. Also, the first element of the list is `a[0]`.

Comment: @poorsod :$ Wow, and I daily program in a 0-indexed language.  It is definitely end of day Friday...  Thanks for the info on `globals()` good to know.

Comment: Also, python has `eval` and `exec` so you can dynamically create *any* bit of code you want. Even though this does not mean that it is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks poorsod I'll check into them lists more, basically my program is going to add polynomials an the variables (or list now) is to separate the different monomials, and since I don't know how many monomials there will be in the polynomial, I needed a way to make the number flexible.

Comment: @Nick the length of a list is flexible. There is no question that they are the right tool for the job

Comment: Thanks everyone i'll use lists then.

Answer (score 1):

I spent at least five minutes trying to think why you would want to do this in the first place, until I decided I could actually write the code in less than five minutes, and hoping that in return you'd tell us why you want to do this.

Here's the code:

```
def new(value):
    highest = -1
    for name in globals():
        if name.startswith('a'):
            try:
                number = int(name[1:])
            except:
                continue

            if number > highest:
                highest = number


    globals()['a%d' % (highest + 1, )] = value


new("zero")
new("one")
new("two")

print a2 # prints two
```

Comment: Like i told poorsod below, "basically my program is going to add polynomials an the variables (or list now) is to separate the different monomials, and since I don't know how many monomials there will be in the polynomial, I needed a way to make the number flexible"

Comment: it doesn't explain why you insist on using variables in a global namespace.  Everyone here is telling you to use a list for good reason, and you seem to think you cannot use lists...  In any case, have you tried my code ? It does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I said I would try to use a list instead of variables, I understand that my idea didn't work an that's why I asked a question. I haven't had a chance to try your code yet but can you explain how it will work in my current code, ill post it in a minute

Comment: Okay i posted my code in the answer if you would show me how to integrate your code.

Comment: I don't have the domain knowledge to understand your code.  The code I gave you though does what you asked for in your original question.  Does it work? Do you understand what it does? Then it's up to you to integrate it in your code.

Comment: Well, I dont really understand what it does though. Like i said i'm pretty new to Python and my program is experimental. Could you elaborate a little bit more on the commands you used?